# How to correctly highlight buttons on click?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, border

So I have built an application in C# using Winforms and my application uses a few different buttons. I'd like to have a highlight on the button that has been clicked to show what 'tab' you're in.

I've tried doing the following;

```
// BUTTONS //
private void dashboard_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load Form
    OpenChildForm(new FormDashboard());
    dashboard_btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red;
    dashboard_btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
}
```

However, this of course doesn't work nicely since it adds a border around the button but when I click another button the border also stays around the previous button.

How would you implement a feature to add a border around the button that get's clicked but have the border disappear after you click another button?

Thank you for any feedback!

**EDIT**:

I've implemented Jimi's advice and used the Leave event to change the border around the button back to 0. However I'm not sure how to implement this in a global way so all my buttons are subscribed to this event.

My code now looks like this;

```
// BUTTONS //
private void dashboard_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load Form
    OpenChildForm(new FormDashboard());

    // Button Highlight
    dashboard_btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red;
    dashboard_btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
}
```

```
// BUTTON REMOVE HIGHLIGHT //
private void dashboard_btn_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dashboard_btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**:

I ended up using Jimi's example and this worked for me :)

Comment: There is a lost focus event for the button control. Within that you could just clear off the border.

Comment: Subscribe to the `Leave` event to restore the original state. Or build a Custom Control that implements this feature, so you do that just once

Comment: I tried this and it worked, thanks. However, I have about 7 buttons, how could I make this generalised so I could use this one method to work on all buttons?

Comment: If you want to use events, subscribe to the Leave event of all Buttons using the same event handler (change in, e.g., `(sender as Button).FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;`)

Comment: Jimi, please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept the answer, this helped me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might lend itself to a `RadioButton` style functionality because clicking a different radio button in the same container will uncheck the others. So, to implement the "generalized approach" that you mention in your comment, you could make a simple custom `RadioButtonEx` class where the `Appearance` property is set to `Button` then change your border style when the `Checked` property changes. In this example, the `Click` event has been changed to `static` so that clicking on any button directs the event to the common `onAnyClick` method.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RadioButtonEx.Click += onAnyClick;
    }

    private void onAnyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = ((RadioButtonEx)sender).Text;
    }
}
public class RadioButtonEx : RadioButton
{
    public static new event EventHandler Click;
    public RadioButtonEx() 
    {
        FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red;
        FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
        Appearance = Appearance.Button;
    }
    protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCheckedChanged(e);
        if(Checked)
        {
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            Click?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/tab-style-button-highlight.git) this sample.

Comment: Thanks, I used the comment of Jimi to solve my problem but this is certainly also a solution. Thanks for the answer :)